# bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitableCommand > /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Tags: xcode, xcode8, codesign

I am trying to run my existing code from one system to another and facing continue following error :

> bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitableCommand
>   /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

How to resolve this error ? I didn't change a single line of code. However in my existing system, its working like a charm. Any hep appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the error you are getting because of some system settings changed. You can solve it by following below steps :

1. This error will say for which pod you are facing this issue. So select that pod file.
2. Now select Target for that Pod
3. Now got To General
4. Tap on Choose info.plist File
5. It will show you pods-yourprojectnae-acknowledgements.plist, so select that option
6. Now Build and check
7. you will not find this error again

This solution works for me. Try once.

Comment: Hey its saved my day. Thanks @kalpesh